# Jquery Alert PHP variable

Tags: php, jquery

Is there away to alert this variable without using ajax?
need guide, trying todo this in one page heres my code.

```
<?php
if($totalActive == 10 OR $totalActive < 10){
echo "<input id='activo' type='hidden' value='$totalActive'>";
?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var tom = $("#activo").val();
    alert("Your Credit Balance will expires in  "+ tom +"days \n Please buy more credits to extend the expire date");
    window.location.href = "Outbox.php";
    </script>
<?php
}//continue php scripts
```

im trying to alert how many days left, does the user have before its credit balance expires, i think you cant combine php with jquery, but is there away to do this?

Comment: No again, the jQuery library is loaded after PHP. Although the alert will work after the PHP has finished executing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call PHP in javascript, but not javascript in PHP.

Also you don't need to do an `OR`, you can just check if `$totalactive` is less than or equal to `10` using `<=`.

```
<?php
  if($totalActive <= 10){
?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    alert("Your Credit Balance will expires in <?php echo $totalActive; ?> days \n Please buy more credits to extend the expire date");
    window.location.href = "Outbox.php";
    </script>
<?php
}
```

Comment: Nicely done. (Side note: We have the same penguins ;))

Answer (score 0):

Another way, which could look more flexible if you want to use that variable in functions or just keep your javascript code in your .js files, would be to get the value in a hidden element such as:

```
<input id="expireDays" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $totalActive; ?>" />
```

Then you would only need to retrieve it with jQuery or javascript on document ready:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var expiredDays = $('#expireDays').val();

   alert("Your Credit Balance will expires in  "+ expiredDays +"days \n Please buy more credits to extend the expire date");

});
```